# Existence and uniqueness of solutions with respect to λ of $\dot x(t) = λx(t) + cos(t)e^{λt}, t > 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

> Consider ODE $\dot x(t) = λx(t) + cos(t)e^{λt}, t > 0$, $x(0)=x_0,\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. Investigate existence and uniqueness of solutions with respect to λ and find a closed representation of the solution $x(t)$.

I have just started learning the existence and uniqueness of solution of ODE and I found this exercise from my textbook. However, I don't know which theorem I should use to investigate the existence and uniqueness of above ODE. Can anyone give me some hints?

For approximate of solution part, I guess if $\lambda <0$ then $x'\approx \lambda x(t)$ and $\dot x \approx cos(t)e^{\lambda t}, \lambda >0$. Am I corrected? Thank you in advance

Comment: $$(e^{-\lambda t}x(t))'=e^{-\lambda t}(x'(t)-\lambda x(t))=\cos t=(\sin t)'$$

Answer (score 5):

If you set $$f(t,y)=\lambda y+\cos(t)e^{\lambda t},$$ this function is Lipschitz refer to $y$, and thus, by [Picard theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) $$\dot x(t)=f(t,x(t))$$ has a unique solution.

Comment: It means that the system has solution for every $\lambda$?? Do you know the approximate solution?

Comment: Yes, for any $\lambda$. For an approximation, I think that you can solve it using the constante variation.

Comment: I look at Picard theorem but it only ensure the system has solution on interval $[t_0-\delta, t_0+\delta]$. But in my question it requires for all $t>0$

Comment: $|f(t,y)-f(t,y)|=|\lambda||x-y|$, and thus the Lipshitz constant don't depend of $t$ for all $t\in\mathbb R$, therefore the solution is global.